# how to login to main domain and subdomain multi tenant?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

i am using package for **multi-tenant**

> multi tenant for spatie

*my system have that :*

every user has it's own database and subdomain,

i need when the user login in main domain and redirect to it's subdomain keep logged in.

i have tried

```
config(['session.domain'=>'.example.com']);
```

and

```
config(['session.domain'=>'*.example.com']);
```

and i set the config session itself

and set

```
session_driver => 'cookie'
session_driver=>'file'
```

thanks.

Comment: Where exactly are you changing config values (loginController)? Also you should avoid chaning config, these values are normally cached on production.

Comment: i tried in service provider and in controller 
it's not working 
i clear cach on production but it's not work in local also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to help those who will have save issue,
i just did next

in main login i did that

```
\DB::purge('tenant');
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', 'main_database');
$user = auth()->user();
$token = Str::random(64);
$user->login_token = $token;
$user->save();
\DB::purge('tenant');
                            
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', Tenant::where('domain', 
auth()->user()->domain)->first()->database);
User::where('email', $user->email)->first()->update(['login_token' => $token]);
return redirect()->to('http://' . auth()->user()->domain . '.' . env('APP_URL') . "/login/$token");
```

and i login get i did that

```
public function loginGet($token = null)
{

    if ($token) {
        $user = User::where('login_token', $token)->first();
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        $user->login_token = null;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```